# How to get the text inside a div inside an iframe in js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am Adel and I am creating a gaming app that works with PHP, js, and HTML, now what I want is a way to get a text from div with the id 'value1' inside an iframe with the id 'ServerData' in js.

This file is stored locally in  my program that runs php, js, and html files:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://website.com/file.php">
<div id="value1">
AnText
</div>
</iframe>
<script>
  the script 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as you page? Browser will not allow you to do anything with the iframe if it is from the different domain

Comment: it's from a different domain, because the file that needs to get the data is stored locally

Comment: You can not access the iframe content then, the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) prevents that.

Comment: but my program allows that because it's just for my website

Comment: Try : var value = document.getElementById("value1").innerText

Comment: but this script will give me the dives

Comment: Please try this var value = $('#iframeId').contents().find('#value1').text();

Answer (score 0):

You can use textContent:

```
 var textDiv = document.getElementById("value1").textContent;
```